# KNN model with two classes in the train dataset and three in classes in test

Tags: machine-learning, k-nn

I have a dataset like this:

```
db_data <- iris[1:100,]

row_train <- sample(nrow(db_data), nrow(db_data)*0.8)
db_train <- iris[row_train,]
db_test1 <- iris[-row_train,]
db_test2 <- iris[101:150,]
db_test <- rbind(db_test1, db_test2)
```

so, my dataset are composed in thise way:

```
> table(db_train$Species)

    setosa versicolor  virginica 
        40         40          0 
> table(db_test$Species)

setosa versicolor  virginica 
    10         10        100
```

So in the train dataset I have two classes, while in the test dataset I have three.
I try this ML model in Rstudio:

```
model_knn<-train(Species ~ ., data = db_train, method = "knn",tuneGrid = data.frame(k = c(2:20)))
summary(model_knn)
#-------

#PREDICTION NEW RECORD
#-------
test_data <- db_test
db_test$predict <- predict(model_knn, newdata=test_data, interval='confidence')
confusionMatrix(data=factor(db_test$predict),reference=factor(db_test$Species))
```

but when I run it I have this error:

```
Error: One or more factor levels in the outcome has no data: 'virginica'
```

How can I solve it? There is another model that can I test?

Thanks

Comment: 'So in the train dataset I have two classes, while in the test dataset I have three.': This is not an optimal splitting. You need to split your datasets in a better way so that the model learns about one other type of class and the respective signals.

Comment: @Shibaprasadb yes i know, but in my original dataset i have this kind of problem. In the train dataset I can only put two classes, I can't split it so that I have all of them